# Check for certain value in every key of a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have the following line:

```
<button className={`actionBoxButton ${props.moves[0].moveName !== "FirstPassMove" && props.moves[0].moveName !== "PassMove"  ? "actionBoxButtonGrey" : ''}`}
```

What it does is to check if the object "moves" has the value "FirstPassMove" for the key moveName. If so, I want it so switch to another style. This is working well.
But what I want to achieve is, to not only check the element 0 of the object, but all the objects  and check if there is a moveName "FirstPassMove" in any element of the object.
It is written in React 16.12

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your jsx by defining a separate function for dynamic className like this:

```js
const check = () => {
 let className_ = "";
    // if this.props.moves is an array, use of instead of in
 for(let i in this.props.moves) {
  if((this.props.moves[i].moveName !== "FirstPassMove") && (this.props.moves[i].moveName !== "PassMove")) {
   className_ = "actionBoxButtonGrey";
  }
 }

 return className_;
}
```

```html
<button className={this.check()}>button</button>
```

Comment: cool, thanks for that! the idea of using an external function with a for loop really did solve the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add className in case at least one of your moves has `FirstPassMove` or `PassMove` name you should use [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ca/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objectes_globals/Array/some)

```
const hasPass = moves.some(({ moveName }) => (
  moveName === "FirstPassMove" || 
  moveName === "PassMove"
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to check that all the `moves` satisfy the constraint, in which case, you can use `Array.prototype.every` to ensure every move satisfies the constraint. If you only need some `moves` to satisfy the constraint, you may use `Array.prototype.some` instead.

```js
// For example
const props = {
    moves: [
        { moveName: 'FirstPassMove' },
        { moveName: 'PassMove' },
        { moveName: 'PassMove' },
        { moveName: 'OtherPassMove' },
    ]
};

function isValidMove({ moveName }) {
    return moveName !== "FirstPassMove"
        && moveName !== "PassMove";
}


function getActionBoxButtonClassName(hasColor) {
    return `actionBoxButton ${hasColor ? "actionBoxButtonGrey" : ''}`;
}

console.log([
    getActionBoxButtonClassName(props.moves.every(isValidMove)),
    getActionBoxButtonClassName(props.moves.some(isValidMove))
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
props.moves.includes('FirstPassMove')
```

Assuming your `props.moves` is an array it will return true or false if this string is inside the `props.moves` array